# I need coordinates of angles some rectangle area (like crop rectangle) on image/photo. How i can get them?

Tags: android, image, coordinates, crop

I need some activity with image cropping, but without getting crop image, just need coordinates angles of rectangle area on image which i can move and resize. How i can make this or where i can find such library with this functional? Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose you better to use Android Canvas. When you touch a particular point you can get details of that point using 'OnTouch'(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) method in android.